# Was Jesus referring to Satan in the parable of honor?

Tags: luke

In Luke 14:7-11, Jesus tells of a parable where he teaches that when one is invited to a wedding banquet, then one should not sit at the place of honor as someone more distinguished than you may be invited and he who invited you both comes and says to you

*Give this man your seat*

And you begin with *shame to take the lowest place*

Could the subject have been Satan because he took a place of honor in heaven and then God came down to him and asked him to give up his place for it belongs to the Christ and the proceeded to take the lowest place even below men?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Satan was ***given*** a place of honour in heaven before he rebelled against God. Then he tried to usurp God's rightful place over all creation. Some take the words in Isaiah 14:9-20 to apply to Satan, said to 'be fallen from heaven', who strove to 'ascend into heaven', to 'be like the most High' [God]. Others do not. But it is certainly true that before he became Satan he was highly exalted by God in heaven, but has now been cast down to Earth (Luke 10:18, Revelation 12:9). Binding, then casting into the eternally burning lake of sulphuric fire follows.

None of that equates with the parable of the great supper in Luke 14:7-11. Satan is not an invited guest to the marriage supper of the Lamb (which this parable points towards - Revelation 19:7 & 21:2). Looking at this parable, Jesus had just said:

> "When thou makest a dinner or a supper, call not thy friends, nor thy
> brethren, neither thy kinsmen, nor thy rich neighbours; lest they also
> bid thee again, and a recompense be made thee. But when thou makest a
> feast, call the poor, the maimed, the lame, the blind; and thou shalt
> be blessed; for they cannot recompense thee: for thou shalt be
> recompensed at the resurrection of the just." Luke 14:12-14 A.V.

Then a man responded said, "Blessed is he that shall eat bread in the kingdom of God."

That one comment was what prompted Jesus to give the parable of the great supper. This shows that Jesus was looking ahead to the great supper in the kingdom of heaven. The spiritually poor, lame, blind etc are invited by God who (in another parable about the wedding supper, Matthew 22:1-14) took the place of the many who had been invited first, but who refused to attend. Comparing both parables will be instructive, for there one man not wearing the wedding garments provided by the host was thrown out in shame as a gate-crasher.

Nobody and nothing can oust the Son of God from his eternal place in the bosom of the Father, as his only-begotten Son. Satan was created. The Son is the Word who made everything that was made (John 1:1-3). That puts the one who became Satan in his place, which he then forfeited by trying to usurp the very throne of God. So, **my answer is that Luke 14:7-11 has nothing whatever to do with Satan.**

Comment: Have you thought about the very thing that might have made Lucifer contend is that he viewed himself equal to the begotten son and asked himself why The Christ gets worship and He is Son much like Satan was a son to God but through creation and then he went to the angels and conspired against worship to Jesus who is a son like them?

Comment: Not seeking to justify his rebellion but I am trying to understand his psychology. He knew he was a created being and knew he didn't stand a fraction of a chance against God, I read that he was a cherub that stood exactly where God's presence manifested itself in heaven. Maybe he lusted after God's throne as is the main stream belief

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel Lucifer could hardly have considered himself as equal to the ONLY begotten Son who had made him! He, a creature, the Son begotten, not made! As for trying to understand that evil one's psychology, go by what the Son said of the devil, "He was a murderer from the beginning, and abode not in the truth because there is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he speaketh of his own, for he is a liar, and the father of it." John 8:44 Let Jesus warn you on that score!

Comment: "Satan is not an invited guest to the marriage supper of the Lamb" +1

Comment: I keep imaging people squabbling over the lowest place.

Answer (score 1):

Luke 14 starts by saying that Jesus attended a banquet hosted by a prominent Pharisee and that He was being 'watched' for whatever he said. We see him curing a man on the way. He may have been a bit late and had to wade through the guests to reach the seat meant for him. He used the opportunity to cut across a lesson of etiquette and social behaviour to the people around him. The lesson is of practical importance and is applicable irrespective of the platform in which it is put forth. It is equally applicable to an assembly of non-believers, as is to believers. The next parable in the same chapter dealing with the banquet dress code, of course, has spiritual connotations. But even there, you cannot say that the person who sat at the table ignoring the dress code was Satan.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the marriage supper of the lamb is repeated for all eternity in heaven. If so, the people who did not wear proper garments, and who were cast out, were so because they left chastity in heaven because they had started to lust the opposite gender there. As with Judas someone else from the queue of applicants from a lower plane would then be picked to fill the vacant spots. Thus, the passage probably doesn't apply to Satan per se, but to people with a leaning towards his thought-world. People in heaven who did not persist in their high calling but abandoned their heavenly position.

Comment: I don't think the angels have a gender